# Solve $x^6 \equiv x \pmod{396}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have to solve the following equation:

> $x^6 \equiv x \pmod {396}$, with $x \in \mathrm{Z}/396\mathrm{Z} $.

So I rewrote this equations as the following system:

$$x^6 \equiv x \pmod4\\  
x^6 \equiv x \pmod9\\
x^6 \equiv x \pmod{11}$$

And I use the fact that $\phi(4)=2$ and $\phi(9)=6$ to rewrite this system again into

$$1 \equiv x \pmod 4\\1 \equiv x\pmod 9\\x^6 \equiv x \pmod{11}$$

But if I use the same reasoning for $\textrm{mod }11$, I get (by $\phi(11)=10$) that 
$$(x^6)^2 \equiv x^{12} \equiv x^2 \equiv (x \pmod{11})^2 \equiv x^2\pmod{11}$$
 which doesn't really help me with solving this equation. How should I solve this equation? Is using the Euler function the proper way or is my reasoning totally wrong?

Comment: You have to be careful because you don't know if $x$ is invertible mod 396, or mod 4, or mod 9, or mod 11. We have, for example, the "obvious" solution $x \equiv 0 \mod 396.$ The decomposition of the problem into "mod 4", "mod 9", and "mod 11" looks good to me. But then you have to be more careful. Mod 4 and mod 9, you have to deal with non-invertible elements. Since 11 is a prime, we have mod 11 that either $x\equiv 0 \mod 11$ or $x^5\equiv 1\mod 11.$ Since the multiplicative group mod 11 is cyclic of order 10, there are exactly 2 solutions to this equation.

Comment: $x^6-x=x(x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$

Comment: @jflipp the question states that I need to find a solution for which $x \not\equiv 0,1 (\textrm{mod }396$ So I suppose there should be more. I edited the question, perhaps my solution should work now

Comment: As jflipp says, you must check the cases $\gcd(x,4)\neq 1,\gcd(x,9)\neq 1, \gcd(x,11)\neq 1$, since $a^{\phi(x)}\equiv 1\pmod x$ holds when $\gcd(a,x)=1$.

Comment: But how should I solve this equation then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Step 1:* (which you already did) Consider $x^6\equiv x\pmod{4}, \pmod{9}$ and $\pmod{11}$ separately.

*Step 2:* To find the solutions to each congruence, you cannot reduce the polynomial using Euler's Theorem as the solution might not be relatively prime to $4$ or $9$. **The good news is $4,9$ and $11$ are small, so we can find all the solutions by trial and error: raising each congruence class $a$ to $a^6$ and check if they are equal.** A quick computation gives

$x^6\equiv x \pmod{4}\Leftrightarrow x\equiv 0,1\pmod{4}$

$x^6\equiv x \pmod{9}\Leftrightarrow x\equiv 0,1\pmod{9}$

$x^6\equiv x \pmod{11}\Leftrightarrow x\equiv 0,1,3,4,5,9\pmod{11}$

*Step 3:* For each combination of solutions modulo $4,9$ and $11$, use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to find the solution modulo $396$. For example,

$\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
x\equiv 0 &\pmod{4}\\
x\equiv 1 & \pmod{9}\\
x\equiv 9 & \pmod{11}\\
\end{array}\right. \Leftrightarrow 
x\equiv 64\pmod{396}$.

I will leave the remaining works to you. You should be able to get $24$ solutions modulo $396$.